# How to return value from for loop using Dart

Tags: for-loop, flutter, dart, return-value

I have the following for loop in Dart:

```
 Locations allLocations(AsyncSnapshot<Results> snap) {
    for (var i = 0; i < snap.data.locationList.length; i++) {
      return snap.data.locationList[i];
    }
  }
```

My goal is to iterate through the list of locations, which I'm getting through a snapshot, and then return each value. Unfortunately, the Dart analyzer is telling me, that this function doesn't end with a return statement. Well, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong in this example.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: What is Locations? Can you share Locations class

Comment: Location class consists of two parameters such as ```latitude``` and ```longitude```. I'm loading a json file with information about locations therefore I have a snapshot of  this loaded data. Now I want to show markers on google maps. In order to show every marker I need to iterate through the list of data.

Comment: A function call can only *return* once. Returning more than once is not meaningful, so it's not clear what it is you want to achieve. So, what is it that you *actually* want to achieve?

Comment: I'll be taking the approach from Ibrahim. 
What I want to achieve is, to read every data stored in a list and display it on the screen. I cannot just use a ListView.builder or similar because those are coordinates which represent points on a map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think u want something like this

```
Stream<int> allInts(List<int> list) async* {
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      yield list.elementAt(i);
    }
  }
```

And when i use this

```
allInts(<int>[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]).listen((number) {
  print(number);
});
```

Console:

```
I/flutter (24597): 1
I/flutter (24597): 3
I/flutter (24597): 5
I/flutter (24597): 7
I/flutter (24597): 9
```

Comment: This is somewhat in the right direction. I think I can work with that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 Locations allLocations(AsyncSnapshot<Results> snap) {
  List returnedList = new List();
  for (var i = 0; i < snap.data.locationList.length; i++) {
    returnedList.add(snap.data.locationList[i]);
  }
  return returnedList;
}
```

Comment: As I told Ravinder Kumar in the above comment. My ```snap.data.locationList``` is already a list. I don't want to return a complete list, but every value from the list. I need each individual value from the list because I want to display every value.

Answer (score 0):

You must not return value at every index, otherwise, the function will be returned at first index only and will not go through complete iteration. Rather, you should return complete list outside loop.

```
List<Locations> mList= new List();
```

```
Locations allLocations(AsyncSnapshot<Results> snap) {
for(var i in  snap.data.locationList){
      mList.add(return snap.data.locationList[i]);
  }
return snap.data.locationList;
}
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure whether I understood your solution. My ```snap.data.locationList```is already a list. I don't want to return a complete list, but every value from the list. I need each individual value from the list because I want to display every value.

Comment: if you use `return` inside a loop then return will exit the loop on very 1st index, I hope you get it.

Comment: I got that point. This doesn't solve my issue. I want to return every value from the list ```snap.data.locationList```. When I'm copying your code into the IDE it complains that I'm using a return statement within my ```mList.add()```. Also the ```i```within the ```snap.data.locationList[i]``` is not a ```int``` type rather it is from type ```Location```  because you writing ```var i in snap.data.locationList```. So there are might be some things wrong.

Comment: I have written this to to clear the concept. I did not write this in my IDE. Also if you want to display something than you must return a list from here and take a listview.count inside your build function.